# For what values of a,b this function satisfies the following differential equation and initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If i have this function:

$$ x(t)= a\cdot e^t + b\cdot e^{-2\cdot t} $$

(1). For what values of $a$ and $b$ this function satisfies the following differential equation:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}+2\cdot x = e^t $$

(2). What is the solution for this equation of the initial value $x(0)=2$

For (1) i solve to get this:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}+2\cdot x = e^t \implies 3\cdot a^{e\cdot t} = e^t $$

and then i get here:

$$ t = e^t\cdot ln(3\cdot a) \implies \frac{e}{3}^{\frac{t}{e^t}}=a$$

or this:

$$ dx = (e^t - 2\cdot x)\cdot dt$$

in order to integrate it and get:

$$ x = e^t - 2\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}$$

But i don't know how to follow.

Comment: there is no need to put a dot $\cdot$ to indicate multiplication; it is understood.

Comment: Hint: there is a mistake or typo in (1). You have $3ae^t=t$ not $3a^{et}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do is to substitute $$ x = ae^t + be^{-2t} $$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants in $$\frac{dx}{dt} + 2x = e^t.$$

when we do that we find $$ae^t - 2be^{2t} + 2a^t + 2be^{2t} = e^t $$ this identity requires $$ a = \frac13, b = \text{ anything,  } \, x = \frac13e^t + b e^{-2t}$$

now, we have to choose $b$ so that $$x(0) = 2, \text{ that is }\frac13 + b = 2 \implies b = \frac53.$$

the final solution is $$x = \frac13e^t + \frac53e^{-2t}. $$

Comment: how do you get that $\frac{1}{3} + b = 3 $?

Comment: @user137201, that was a mistake. is fixed now.